# MuleSoft NetSuite Connector Search

Tags: java, spring, mule

I am trying to figure out how to get values from the returned Search payload using the NetSuite Connector in Mulesoft.

Whenever I use this connector, it returned an output of `List<Map<String, Object>>`, I am unsure if there is a way to use DataWeave and map the values returned, because of this type of output.

Is there a way to actually get the components of this List, and map it to something else using Dataweave?

In one example, I am grabbing the internalId of a search result record using `#[payload.hasNext() ? 'Employee Found: ' + payload.next().get('internalId') : 'Employee Not Found']` and I can successfully get the value.

In another case where I am trying to use that internalId with the NetSuite Connector 'Get Record' functionality, I try to input an internalId parameter `payload.next().get('internalId')` the same way and get an error as follows.

```
<netsuite:get-record config-ref="NetSuite_Login_Auth" internalId="#[payload.next().get('internalId')]" type="EMPLOYEE" doc:name="NetSuite"/>
```

**ERROR:**

> Message               : Failed to invoke getRecord. Payload
>   : org.mule.streaming.ConsumerIterator@20969555 Payload Type          :
>   org.mule.streaming.ConsumerIterator Element               :
>   /streamMigrateAccountToCustomer/processors/10/0/1/0/1/searchEmployeeByEntityId/subprocessors/3/1/0
>   @ sfdc-netsuite-api Element XML           : 
>                           
>                           
>                           
>                           
>                           
>                           
>                           
>                           
>   -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Root Exception stack trace: java.util.NoSuchElementException     at
>   org.mule.streaming.AbstractConsumer.consume(AbstractConsumer.java:70)
>     at org.mule.streaming.ConsumerIterator.next(ConsumerIterator.java:60)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor148.invoke(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the values and pass it inside a batch execute and do the mapping inside the  batch

```
 <flow name="swt-ns-data-pull">
            <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
                <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
    %output application/java
    ---
    {
        basic: {
            lastModifiedDate: {
                operator: "AFTER",
                searchValue: flowVars.modifiedDate
            },
            recordType: {
                operator: "IS",
                searchValue: "vendorPayment"
            }
        }
    } as :object {
        class : "com.netsuite.webservices.transactions.sales.TransactionSearch"
    }
    ]]></dw:set-payload>
            </dw:transform-message>
            <logger message="started" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
            <netsuite:search config-ref="NetSuite__Request_Level_Token_Based_Authentication" searchRecord="TRANSACTION" bodyFieldsOnly="false" fetchSize="1000" doc:name="NetSuite"/>
        </flow>
```

**Mapping Inside batch**

```
<batch:step name="RemittanceDetailCreation">
                <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
                <batch:set-record-variable variableName="rec" value="#[payload]" doc:name="Record Variable"/>
                <dw:transform-message metadata:id="b7f75c92-a6c7-423a-8faa-cb9080914888" doc:name="Transform Message">
                    <dw:input-payload mimeType="application/json" doc:sample="C:\Users\sathekumar\Desktop\VedorPayment.json"/>
                    <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/csv header = false
%var NIC=sizeOf payload.applyList.apply
---
payload.applyList.apply map (( payment, indexOfPayment) ->{
    NumberInCollection: '"' ++ NIC ++ '"' when NIC != null otherwise null,
    ExternalPayableReferenceNumber: null,
    ExternalSecondaryPayableReferenceNumber: null,
    AdjustmentAmount: null,
    DiscountAmount: '"' ++ payment.discAmt ++ '"' when payment.discAmt != null otherwise null,
    GrossAmount: '"' ++ (payment.total as :string) ++ '"' when payment.total != null otherwise null,
    NetAmount: '"' ++ (payment.amount as :string) ++ '"' when payment.amount != null otherwise null,
    PayableDate: payload.PayableDate,
    PayableReferenceNumber: paylaod.PR,
    PayableType: null,
    SecondaryPayableReferenceNumber: null,
    SecondaryPayableType: null,
    SupplierPayableReferenceNumber: null

})]]></dw:set-payload>
                </dw:transform-message>
                <byte-array-to-string-transformer doc:name="Byte Array to String"/>
                <batch:commit size="1000" doc:name="Batch Commit">
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to actually get the components of this List, and map it to something else using Dataweave?

It is currently not possible. The **Search** operation returns a list of  `Map<String, Object>` without any additional metadata thus making it impossible for DataWeave to identify which components are included. I'm not sure if this responds to a limitation of the NetSuite SOAP API or it just hasn't been implemented in the connector.

> In another case where I am trying to use that internalId with the NetSuite Connector 'Get Record' functionality, I try to input an internalId parameter payload.next().get('internalId') the same way and get an error as follows.

The **Search** operation works because it is a **paginated operation** that wraps the payload inside a `ConsumerIterator` object. However, the **Get Record** is NOT paginated and just returns a `Map<String, Object>`. Therefore, you should be able to obtain the value by calling `payload.get('internalId')`.